# Maximum Likelihhod Classification - Error 010108 and Error 010067

Tags: raster, arcmap, classification, composite, likelihood

I'm trying to run a supervised classification on a Landsat8 multi-band raster in ArcMap. Every time I run the classification, it returns `Error 010108` and `Error 010067`. The 010108 error says

`The number of bands in the signature file is less than the number of bands in the raster`

So I tried using the **Composite Bands** tool to compress my raster to a single band, but it still returns a raster with the same number of bands as the original.

- Is compressing my multi-band raster to a one-band raster the right solution?
- If so, how do I do so without extracting bands individually?

I can't find any other suggested tool than Composite Bands, and it's still just producing an identical multi-band raster.

Comment: what software are you using? Please update your question using  the [edit] button or add a relevant tag.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which fixed my problem, but I changed the name of my signature file so that it ended in a numeral (e.g., filename_2015 instead of 2015_filename) and saved all my files to my desktop instead of the home folder. After that it suddenly worked every time I ran it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you ensure that the raster file upon which you created training samples is the same as the input raster in the Maximum Likelihood Classifier tool.

[image: ML Classifier screenshot]

Using the above image as a example, ensure the raster file for training samples (blue square) is the same raster you input in the Maximum Likelihood Classifier tool (Red square).

After series of trial and error, this was a precise solution to the problem for me. I hope it helps.